# PIE CSS: rgba backgrounds + box shadows

Tags: internet-explorer, css, css3pie

I noticed that with CSS like

```
body {
    background: #f00;
}
div {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    -pie-background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    padding: 50px;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

I will get the below in FireFox & IE/PIE

[image]

is it possible to fix that? the box shadow showing through the rgba background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bad news for you: It doesn't look like it works.

According to the [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie.com/) website, it supports RGBA colours, but...

> Currently all color stops are rendered fully opaque, even if specifying an rgba color value. This is due to a limitation in VML's linear gradient syntax which does not allow setting opacity for individual color stops.

(see http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/)

They also have a ticket logged for it: https://github.com/lojjic/PIE/issues#issue/7

Comment: erm, its not actually gradients, for this to actually work, PIE will have to somehow "mask" the shadow directly under the the background ...

Comment: @jiewmeng: that's what the 'A' is in RGBA - it's the Alpha chanel, which gives semi-transparency. That's the effect he's trying to use, but PIE doesn't support it, so it's just using the RGB value and ignoring the A, which is what is causing his problem.